# Smartface: How to enter data in a web service?

Tags: android, ios, authentication, smartface.io

I want to create a sign up page and I have a web service ready for it to receive the data. I have set the web service in Smartface but don't know how to get my data from the Editbox object to that web service on a button click. Help me solve this problem, a guide will be helpful.

Comment: seem like you haven't searched that on google , this isn't a teaching class

Comment: I have searched that on google but can't find the ans so i asked here

Answer (score 0):

There are  guides about using WebServices .

I suggest you to read guides about it ;

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides ( Data & Network section )

Comment: I have gone through this but can't find how should I send the data from editbox to a webservice if you have any example plz  me.Thanks